# configuration jax-rs web service

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am trying to implement a jax-rs web service using jersey framework. I have written the web service but I don't fully understand what the web.xml tags.so I don't know if I have configured it correct but when I try to access the service I get an error. Here is the web service:

```
package com.Test.rest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
@Path("/demo")
public class DemoService extends Application
{
    @GET
    @Path("/welcome")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String sayWelcome()
    {
        return "welcome.."; 
    }
}
```

web.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.Test.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resorces/*</url-pattern>
```

getting error:-

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:669)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Recheck your dependencies..post your pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AbstractMethodError are thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method.

uri is an abstract method in UriBuilder, so you need an implementation of this. This method (with String parameter) is from version 2.0 of JAX-RS specification.

You're trying to use JAX-RS 2.0 with Jersey 1.*. Instead, you need to use Jersey 2.* that implements JAX-RS 2.0 and contains an implementation to uri method.

Comment: Thank you but please explain in detail,because I am fresher in web-service tech.I am not getting

Comment: are you using maven ?